# Print Message in Console if cppunit is successful

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, cppunit

I created my first test class with the Netbeans Test creating function and all test passed.

Now i would like to print in the main in the terminal window "Success" if test x passes.

I thought something like:

```
void test(bool testResult)
{
 if(testResult==true)
 cout << "Success";
}
```

Parameter testResult should be the result of test x.

But where and how do i get that status from?

How to check the status of tests in main ?

Update:
i got now this:

```
 void test(bool testResult)
{
if(testResult==true)
 {
   cout << "Success";
 }else cout << "Failure";
}



int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
....
test(newtestclass);  //included my testclass.h and put the test class as parameter
}
```

i get now only 1 error in Netbeans:
"main.cpp:59:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token"

Answer (score 0):

You are mainly referencing a method. Try this:

```
test();
```

in the `Main ()` or anywhere, where you would think it should work! But remember to always include a parameter inside the method such as:

```
Main(/* anything */) {
   bool x = true;
   test(x);
}
```

This way, the code will execute and in the beginning it will go for the method, and will execute it! It will use the value of the x bool, and will run as you have written the method for it!

Secondly,

```
if(testResult == true) {
```

has the same meaning as

```
if(testResult) {
```

Second method is better and shorter.

Comment: i have updated my question with my latest code. dont know how to use code in comments. 4 blanks dont work to use code formatting.